# Hide Windows application from taskbar while still having it opened on second monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10

As the title says, I have to find a way to hide a Windows from the taskbar while still having it open on the second monitor. I need to recourd a video course and I don't want my scenario to be seen in the taskbar. Is this possible in any way? I tried to find any on Google for about 1hr, but nothing helped me.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows 10 supports 2 taskbars and if you use this, you can specify if only the apps on screen are shown on the taskbar or not. Have you looked into this and is this not what you want, or did you actually not know this was possible? (I post this as a comment and not an answer for this reason)

Comment: No, I didn't know. I found something about multiple desktops, but I have to switch between them, and that would not help me. Can you detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple taskbars for multiple desktops.

The setting can be found if you do the following:

- Right-click on the taskbar, and select taskbar properties.

In the settings, scroll down and enable:

Multiple Displays

- Show taskbar on all monitors [on]

Change show `taskbar buttons on...` in the dropdown to:

- Taskbar with open windows